# SVG animation doesn't work on favicon in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

In the `<head>` SVG favicon is set

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.svg" sizes="any" type="image/svg+xml">
```

This is the content of SVG file which rotates the inner circle. Favicon animation doesn't work at all in Chrome.

How to make it work in Chrome? In Firefox it works ok, in Edge it doesn't but Chrome is the most important

```html
<svg width=" 54" height="54" viewBox="0 0 54 54" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="27" cy="27" r="25" stroke="#005C97" stroke-width="3" />
    <circle class="logo-eye" cx="35" cy="21" r="7" fill="#005C97" />
    <style>
    @keyframes rotations {
        to {
            transform: rotate(360deg)
        }
    }
    circle {
        animation: rotations 4s linear infinite;
        display: block;
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        will-change: transform;
    }
    </style>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing CSS animation with SMIL rotation animation:

```html
<svg width=" 54" height="54" viewBox="0 0 54 54" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="27" cy="27" r="25" stroke="#005C97" stroke-width="3" />
    
    <circle class="logo-eye" cx="35" cy="21" r="7" fill="#005C97" >
     <animateTransform id="an"  attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="0 27 27;360 27 27" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither CSS nor SMIL works in Chrome or Edge on Windows. Firefox is the only browser that responds to non-js animated favicons. Unless there's a special syntax required to animate favicons in WebKit browsers that I'm unaware of...?

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not supported by Google Chromium. This isn't a bug either, it just doesn't seem to be a requirement.

Looking at the Google [Chromium Favicon status pages](https://chromestatus.com/features), the only required Favicon SVG feature is this one: https://chromestatus.com/feature/5180316371124224.
It is also marked as fully implemented by specification. So if we want this feature, we should make a feature request.

So far I haven't found any.

An easy method to try out whether the browser supports SVG animation in the favicon, and which one, is provided by this page: https://animated-svg-favicon.glitch.me.

**CSS**, **JS** and **SML** animations can be tested.