# How to get SVG (img) to follow css animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

I am trying to get My SVG image here to animate like the noted-out section does. My image file always appears broken, but still, loads the effects. I have tried adding this as you see it now and have tried this with multiple effects. The image never seems to want to load, but the broken icon usually dawns the effects.

```css
body {
      color: #ccc;
      background: #111;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    h1,
    h2 {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    a {
      color: #ccc;
    }
    
    section {
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .hero {
      font-size: clamp(40px, 10vw, 100px);
      line-height: 1;
      display: inline-block;
      color: #fff;
      z-index: 2;
      letter-spacing: 10px;
    
      /* Bright things in dark environments usually cast that light, giving off a glow */
      filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 3px);
    }
    
    .demo {
      height: 100px;
      background: #fff;
    }
    
    .layers {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .layers::before,
    .layers::after {
      content: attr(data-text);
      position: absolute;
      width: 110%;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    
    .layers::before {
      top: 10px;
      left: 15px;
      color: #e0287d;
    }
    
    .layers::after {
      top: 5px;
      left: -10px;
      color: #1bc7fb;
    }
    
    .single-path {
      clip-path: polygon(
        0% 12%,
        53% 12%,
        53% 26%,
        25% 26%,
        25% 86%,
        31% 86%,
        31% 0%,
        53% 0%,
        53% 84%,
        92% 84%,
        92% 82%,
        70% 82%,
        70% 29%,
        78% 29%,
        78% 65%,
        69% 65%,
        69% 66%,
        77% 66%,
        77% 45%,
        85% 45%,
        85% 26%,
        97% 26%,
        97% 28%,
        84% 28%,
        84% 34%,
        54% 34%,
        54% 89%,
        30% 89%,
        30% 58%,
        83% 58%,
        83% 5%,
        68% 5%,
        68% 36%,
        62% 36%,
        62% 1%,
        12% 1%,
        12% 34%,
        60% 34%,
        60% 57%,
        98% 57%,
        98% 83%,
        1% 83%,
        1% 53%,
        91% 53%,
        91% 84%,
        8% 84%,
        8% 83%,
        4% 83%
      );
    }
    
    .paths {
      animation: paths 5s step-end infinite;
    }
    
    @keyframes paths {
      0% {
        clip-path: polygon(
          0% 43%,
          83% 43%,
          83% 22%,
          23% 22%,
          23% 24%,
          91% 24%,
          91% 26%,
          18% 26%,
          18% 83%,
          29% 83%,
          29% 17%,
          41% 17%,
          41% 39%,
          18% 39%,
          18% 82%,
          54% 82%,
          54% 88%,
          19% 88%,
          19% 4%,
          39% 4%,
          39% 14%,
          76% 14%,
          76% 52%,
          23% 52%,
          23% 35%,
          19% 35%,
          19% 8%,
          36% 8%,
          36% 31%,
          73% 31%,
          73% 16%,
          1% 16%,
          1% 56%,
          50% 56%,
          50% 8%
        );
      }
    
      5% {
        clip-path: polygon(
          0% 29%,
          44% 29%,
          44% 83%,
          94% 83%,
          94% 56%,
          11% 56%,
          11% 64%,
          94% 64%,
          94% 70%,
          88% 70%,
          88% 32%,
          18% 32%,
          18% 96%,
          10% 96%,
          10% 62%,
          9% 62%,
          9% 84%,
          68% 84%,
          68% 50%,
          52% 50%,
          52% 55%,
          35% 55%,
          35% 87%,
          25% 87%,
          25% 39%,
          15% 39%,
          15% 88%,
          52% 88%
        );
      }
    
      30% {
        clip-path: polygon(
          0% 53%,
          93% 53%,
          93% 62%,
          68% 62%,
          68% 37%,
          97% 37%,
          97% 89%,
          13% 89%,
          13% 45%,
          51% 45%,
          51% 88%,
          17% 88%,
          17% 54%,
          81% 54%,
          81% 75%,
          79% 75%,
          79% 76%,
          38% 76%,
          38% 28%,
          61% 28%,
          61% 12%,
          55% 12%,
          55% 62%,
          68% 62%,
          68% 51%,
          0% 51%,
          0% 92%,
          63% 92%,
          63% 4%,
          65% 4%
        );
      }
    
      45% {
        clip-path: polygon(
          0% 33%,
          2% 33%,
          2% 69%,
          58% 69%,
          58% 94%,
          55% 94%,
          55% 25%,
          33% 25%,
          33% 85%,
          16% 85%,
          16% 19%,
          5% 19%,
          5% 20%,
          79% 20%,
          79% 96%,
          93% 96%,
          93% 50%,
          5% 50%,
          5% 74%,
          55% 74%,
          55% 57%,
          96% 57%,
          96% 59%,
          87% 59%,
          87% 65%,
          82% 65%,
          82% 39%,
          63% 39%,
          63% 92%,
          4% 92%,
          4% 36%,
          24% 36%,
          24% 70%,
          1% 70%,
          1% 43%,
          15% 43%,
          15% 28%,
          23% 28%,
          23% 71%,
          90% 71%,
          90% 86%,
          97% 86%,
          97% 1%,
          60% 1%,
          60% 67%,
          71% 67%,
          71% 91%,
          17% 91%,
          17% 14%,
          39% 14%,
          39% 30%,
          58% 30%,
          58% 11%,
          52% 11%,
          52% 83%,
          68% 83%
        );
      }
    
      76% {
        clip-path: polygon(
          0% 26%,
          15% 26%,
          15% 73%,
          72% 73%,
          72% 70%,
          77% 70%,
          77% 75%,
          8% 75%,
          8% 42%,
          4% 42%,
          4% 61%,
          17% 61%,
          17% 12%,
          26% 12%,
          26% 63%,
          73% 63%,
          73% 43%,
          90% 43%,
          90% 67%,
          50% 67%,
          50% 41%,
          42% 41%,
          42% 46%,
          50% 46%,
          50% 84%,
          96% 84%,
          96% 78%,
          49% 78%,
          49% 25%,
          63% 25%,
          63% 14%
        );
      }
    
      90% {
        clip-path: polygon(
          0% 41%,
          13% 41%,
          13% 6%,
          87% 6%,
          87% 93%,
          10% 93%,
          10% 13%,
          89% 13%,
          89% 6%,
          3% 6%,
          3% 8%,
          16% 8%,
          16% 79%,
          0% 79%,
          0% 99%,
          92% 99%,
          92% 90%,
          5% 90%,
          5% 60%,
          0% 60%,
          0% 48%,
          89% 48%,
          89% 13%,
          80% 13%,
          80% 43%,
          95% 43%,
          95% 19%,
          80% 19%,
          80% 85%,
          38% 85%,
          38% 62%
        );
      }
    
      1%,
      7%,
      33%,
      47%,
      78%,
      93% {
        clip-path: none;
      }
    }
    
    .movement {
      /* Normally this position would be absolute & on the layers, set to relative here so we can see it on the div */
      position: relative;
      animation: movement 8s step-end infinite;
    }
    
    @keyframes movement {
      0% {
        top: 0px;
        left: -20px;
      }
    
      15% {
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
      }
    
      60% {
        top: 5px;
        left: -10px;
      }
    
      75% {
        top: -5px;
        left: 20px;
      }
    
      100% {
        top: 10px;
        left: 5px;
      }
    }
    
    .opacity {
      animation: opacity 5s step-end infinite;
    }
    
    @keyframes opacity {
      0% {
        opacity: 0.1;
      }
    
      5% {
        opacity: 0.7;
      }
    
      30% {
        opacity: 0.4;
      }
    
      45% {
        opacity: 0.6;
      }
    
      76% {
        opacity: 0.4;
      }
    
      90% {
        opacity: 0.8;
      }
    
      1%,
      7%,
      33%,
      47%,
      78%,
      93% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    
    .font {
      animation: font 7s step-end infinite;
    }
    
    @keyframes font {
      0% {
        font-weight: 100;
        color: #e0287d;
        filter: blur(3px);
      }
    
      20% {
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #fff;
        filter: blur(0);
      }
    
      50% {
        font-weight: 300;
        color: #1bc7fb;
        filter: blur(2px);
      }
    
      60% {
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #fff;
        filter: blur(0);
      }
    
      90% {
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #e0287d;
        filter: blur(6px);
      }
    }
    
    .glitch span {
      animation: paths 5s step-end infinite;
    }
    
    .glitch::before {
      animation: paths 5s step-end infinite, opacity 5s step-end infinite,
        font 8s step-end infinite, movement 10s step-end infinite;
    }
    
    .glitch::after {
      animation: paths 5s step-end infinite, opacity 5s step-end infinite,
        font 7s step-end infinite, movement 8s step-end infinite;
    }
    
    .hero-container {
      position: relative;
      padding: 200px 0;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .environment {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      opacity: 0.5;
      filter: blur(5px);
    
        center no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<section>
    
      <div class="hero-container">
        <div class="environment"></div><span>
        <img class="hero glitch layers" src="C:\Users\John\Downloads\final_logo.svg"
             data-text="SPIFFYY"></span>
        
        
        <!--<h2 class="hero glitch layers" data-text="近設計"><span>近設計</span></h2>-->
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. But if your concern is about the image file failing to load, you might want to replace the local file path with backslashes (`\ `) with relative path with forward slashes (`/`). That is, rather than using `C:\Users\...`, try using `relative/path/to/file` that points to a relative directory to your HTML file.

Comment: Is this just the same Chrome bug as discovered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71382049/svg-animation-doesnt-work-on-favicon-in-chrome i.e. does your animation work in Firefox?

Comment: @RobertLongson No, I was using edge to test this, so I didnt have any chrome bug

Comment: @BumhanYu if you run the code snippet, you will see that the animation is active and working and that It seems to not want to load, thus not being affected by the animation.

Comment: CSS animation is working fine, but the image file isn't loading. That's what I meant with the path notation. Try fixing the path, and once the asset loads its associated CSS declarations might apply.

Comment: I see. If you want to animate `SVG` elements and its properties, you need to use them as inline SVGs. That is, if you use `img` tag to load `svg` files, it'll simply be treated as static graphic file like `JPG` or `PNG`, and any SVG-specific animations won't take effect.

Comment: I changed the path to this https://svgshare.com/i/f4H.svg   @BumhanYu It now displays the image but it does not animate any longer at all.

Comment: See [this Code Pen example](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/xxZgNJ) as a reference. The SVG elements are inlined as part of the page markup.

Comment: there aren't any specific svg animations, its all css usually this can be done on text, and I wanted to see if it could work for an svg

Comment: I see, I will try this out and let you know how it goes, my reason for not wanting to do a svg was for the compability on mobile

Comment: I have tried using the SVG and its just going to take a to tackle that, is there anyway to do this as an image instead of an svg and still have it product random effect orders instead of just making a gif?

Comment: Edge is [just a skin on Chromium these days](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-edge-chromium-1ce9507c-f09d-4de6-a706-eb52f46be90c). They have the same rendering engine and therefore the same bugs.

Comment: @BumhanYu The failure of Chromium to do CSS animation of SVG images would seem to be a recent bug which I imagine will get fixed at some point. It certainly used to work.

Comment: hmm, thanks for all the help guys!